# What Roles required for Service Desk for password reset in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have few users they don't use any system/mobile for SSPR( self service password reset). Users need to call service desk(SD) for password reset.

As I know [user admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#user-administrator) Azure AD role can be given to SD using access package so that they can reset the password when they get call for password reset.

Question is, Is there any other Azure role ( not Azure AD role) available for password reset activities?
I don't want to give the the whole User admin Azure AD role as it has more options to do other Azure AD activities.

Or, Should I customize user admin Azure AD role?

I didn't get any best practice recommendation from Microsoft documents. Any one has faced similar requirement before? How to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple, one of them being the [Password Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#password-administrator) role:

> Users with this role have limited ability to manage passwords. This role does not grant the ability to manage service requests or monitor service health. Whether a Password Administrator can reset a user's password depends on the role the user is assigned.

There is a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#who-can-reset-passwords) that lists a table of what roles can reset password for what role:

[image]